# Install Ubuntu 20.04 on ZFS partition

Tags: system-installation, zfs

I read that I can install now Ubuntu 20.04 using ZFS. Unfortunatly I see this option only available if I wipe the complete drive. Thats bad, I want to dual boot with Windows and I don't want to loose my Windows install, if possible.

**Does anybody have an idea how to install with ZFS without ereasing and using the whole disk?**

Maybe by changing some lines of code of the ubiquity installer script...?

Comment: Seems to be impossible because of the ZFS-pool (see at least [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Data_structures:_Pools,_datasets_and_volumes) and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZFS#Storage_pools ).

Comment: Well, currently I am running 3 devices with other linux distros with a zfs setup, also with dual boot. No problems so far. But I don't want to invest much time in installing if ubuntu is offering me everything. I like the concept of 20.04 by having a good system state by snapshotting. So, I try to get my setup on ubuntu without changing and hacking too much into their defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. It's important to note here that you can do it with the OS on separate drive, and after selecting the option in the next screen you can select the drive you want to install to .

#### However This Does Not Leave the Other Drives Untouched!!

Ubuntu will add grub options for other OS, which in Ubuntu's case is usually a very stable and helpful practice. However in the case of zfs *It bricked my Centos8 install* by messing with /sysroot which had to be manually repaired from rescue mode, a long and arduous process.

I'm putting this here in case someone is considering any kind of dual boot scenario using destructive zfs on root option in Ubuntu Focal Graphical installer and happens to land here. I don't recommend it. Remove your drives first (or disable them in bios), or do a selective install and then install zfs manually. Even then it goes without saying *fully back up your other systems first!*